# Brace expansion with numbers in bash

Tags: bash

This code

```
echo {1..7}
```

prints `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.

But this code

```
t=7
echo {1..$t}
```

prints `{1..7}`.

How do I get `{1..$t}` to expand to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`?

Comment: See [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) for the order of expansions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. Use e.g. `seq` for that, because brace expansion is performed before any other expansions and `eval` is evil :-)

```
$ a=5

$ seq 1 $a
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: See e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval`(evaluate) in shell script.

```
eval echo {1..$t}
```